# ¿como puedo insertar los datos desde checkboxs creados con un while a una base de datos a través de una funcion ajax?

Tags: php, html, ajax

Este es mi checkbox

```
<div class="col-sm-4 text-left" id="checktiptrab">
    <?php
        while ($rowb=mysqli_fetch_array($querytipotrabajo)){
            echo '
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input value= "'.$rowb['codigotipotrabajo'].'" type="checkbox" name="CheckTipoTrabajo" id="CheckTipoTrabajo">
                '.$rowb['descripciontipotrabajo'].'   
            </label>
            <br>
            <br>';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Tomo el valor en mi ajax:

```
var CheckTipoTrabajo=document.getElementById('CheckTipoTrabajo').value;
```

---

Comment: creo que esto es similar a lo que te comparto:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493531/send-multiple-checkbox-data-to-php-via-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 0):

Si vas a enviar los datos al servidor por medio de **AJAX** entonces puedes dejar tu estructura **HTML** así tal cual la tienes, ya que los datos se capturarían con **JavaScript**, se formaría un `array` y se enviaría al **Back-End**.

Lo único que te aconsejaría es cambiar el `id` de los `ckeckbox` por `class`, recuerda que el `id` es un identificador único he irrepetible en el sitio por lo cual si 2 o más elementos van a compartir el mismo nombre es necesario cambiar el `id` por `class`.

```
<div class="col-sm-4 text-left" id="checktiptrab">
    <?php
        while ($rowb = mysqli_fetch_array($querytipotrabajo)){
            echo '
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input value= "'.$rowb['codigotipotrabajo'].'" type="checkbox" name="CheckTipoTrabajo" class="CheckTipoTrabajo">
                '.$rowb['descripciontipotrabajo'].'   
            </label>
            <br>
            <br>';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Te dejo un ejemplo funcional de como debes capturar los valores de los `checkbox` que hayan sido seleccionados, el ejemplo tiene únicamente en **JavaScript** usando la librería **jQuery** para simular el funcionamiento, si te fijas bien los `checkbox` se generan por medio de un ciclo `for` para simular lo más posible el ciclo `while` de tu **PHP**.

```js
for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
    $("#checktiptrab").append('<label class="btn btn-primary"><input value="codigotipotrabajo_'+ i +'" type="checkbox" name="CheckTipoTrabajo" class="CheckTipoTrabajo">Descripcion tipo trabajo '+ i +'</label><br><br>');
}

$("#enviar").click(function(){
    var datos = Array();

    $('[name="CheckTipoTrabajo"]:checked').each(function(index, data){
        datos.push($(data).val());
    });

    console.log(datos);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "archivo_php.php",
        data: {datos:datos},
        success: function(response){
            
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-4 text-left" id="checktiptrab"></div>

<button id="enviar">Enviar</button>
```